# CloudFront ForwardedValues ambiguous documentation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront

I'm configuring my CloudFront using CloudFormation, and on [the AWS documentation page for the `ForwardedValues` property](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-distribution-forwardedvalues.html#cfn-cloudfront-distribution-forwardedvalues-querystring), we can see the following statement:

> If you specify true for `QueryString` and you don't specify any values for `QueryStringCacheKeys`, CloudFront forwards all query string parameters to the origin and **caches** based on all query string parameters.

The word in bold (**caches**) are causing some confusion, as the meaning of this sentence is completely dependent on **caches** being a verb or **caches** being a noun:

- Verb: CloudFormation will cache the queryparameter
- Noun: CloudFormation will forward the queryparameter to the cache, but it will not cache the queryparameters

If I don't specify the `QueryStringCacheKeys`, what is the behaviour of CloudFront?

Comment: The meaning here is *CloudFront forwards all query string parameters to the origin and caches* ***responses*** *based on all query string parameters*.  It's a verb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify the `QueryStringCacheKeys`, but only this:

```
ForwardedValues:
  QueryString: true
```

CloudFront will `Forward all, cache based on all`, which means that the request will be cached based on `url+querystring` and that the querystring is forwarded to the underlying system.

You can read more on this in the AWS documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/QueryStringParameters.html).

---

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I fixed it by specifying `CachePolicyId`

as in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-managed-cache-policies.html

```
    Type: "AWS::CloudFront::Distribution"
    Properties:
      DistributionConfig:
        DefaultCacheBehavior:
          # Name: Managed-CachingOptimized
          # need either this parameter or 'ForwardedValues'
          CachePolicyId: 658327ea-f89d-4fab-a63d-7e88639e58f6
```